# why am I not allowed to debug

Tags: java, debugging

At school when I try to debug my work, a little window pops up that says "Could not connect to a free debugger socket"

this does not happen to my friends when they try debugging their programs, only mine

this also does not happen at home, so if I want to debug, I either give my friends the code or I bring it home on a USB.

this happens in both Eclipse and JGrasp for me.

school computers are running Windows 7

If you know how to fix it, please help me!

Comment: did you try to run your eclipse with administrator privileges ?

Comment: Ask your teacher.

Comment: Maybe the sockets are already in use by another program?

Comment: The phrase  "Could not connect to a free debugger socket" occurs nowhere else on the web other than this question, so either the text is incorrect or this is a problem specific to your school environment, and so all we can do is guess. Best talk to your instructor and/or your school IT people.

Comment: I have tried asking my teacher, and she has no clue why it is doing that. I have also asked my friends but they don't have a clue either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On jGRASP under "Settings" / "Java Debug Settings", you can change the preferred connector to "Shared Memory". You can probably similarly choose the connector type for Eclipse. That should allow you to debug, but I have no idea what the root problem is.